# loading NPAPI plugin inside c++ application

Tags: c++, browser, npapi

I have a DLL that is an npapi plugin that is from another application, this application only opens if it is executed by the plugin that is executed by the browser, however as this type of plugin is no longer supported, I have been researching alternatives to create an application c++ that can call this DLL and do the same function that browsers did, I read a little about the mozilla gecko but from what I see the documentation for this is almost non-existent, is there another alternative to make this call? or just embedding browser functions in c++ application, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can host it yourself, but implementing the host side of NPAPI can be non-trivial -- it would take some work, it really depends on what the plugin wants exactly. Most documentation around NPAPI seems to be down these days as well, so finding the details may take some work.